# Dropdown in loop only gets the first item value from foreach loop php/ajax

Tags: php, ajax, foreach

I got two dropdowns for my product in my cart.
All products are stored in sessions inside of a foreach loop.
But my dropdowns only work for the first product from loop.
Exemple: if i have 2 products in my cart the fisrt product row gets the cost based on both dorpdowns.
but the second product is getting the same cost from the first dropdown.
can someone please tell me how to fix this.

my script in checkout.php

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.fabric, .size').on('change', sendData);

    function sendData() {
      var fabricID = $('.fabric').val();
        var sizeID   = $('.size').val();
        var cost = $(this).attr('data-id');
      if ( fabricID !== "" && sizeID !== "") {
          $.ajax({
                type     : 'GET',
                url      : 'calculates.php',
                dataType : 'json',
                data     : {
                    prod_id:cost,
                    fabric_id: fabricID,
                    size_id: sizeID
                }
            }).done(function(data) {
                $('.icms' + cost).text(data.val);

            });
        }
    }
});
```

My php foreach loop in cart.php

```
function cart(){
    global $conn;


    $fabric_options = '<option>Select Fabric</option>';
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM almofadas";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $tecido=$rows['tecido'];
        $id_price=$rows['id_price'];
        $t50='50';
        $t45='45';

        $fabric_options .= '<option value="'.$id_price.'">'.$tecido.'</option>';
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['icms'])) {
        $_SESSION['icms']='0';
    }else{
        $_SESSION['icms'];
    }

    foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if($value > 0){
            if(substr($name, 0, 8 ) == "product_"){
                $length = strlen($name) -8;
                $item_id = substr($name,8 , $length);

                $query = "SELECT * 
                             FROM gallery2 
                          WHERE gallery2.id =".escape_string($item_id). "";
                $run_item = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_item)){ 
                    $vari   = $rows['variante'];
                    $num    = $rows['title'];
                    $id     = $rows['id'];

                    $btn_add ='<button type="button" class="btn btn-success actions plus" data-action="plus" product_id="'.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" add_btn></i></button>';

                    $btn_remove ='<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning actions less" data-action="remove" product_id="'.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" remove_btn></i></button>';

                    $btn_delete ='<button type="button" class="btn btn-default actions" data-action="delete" product_id="'.$id.'" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>';

                    if($rows['variante'] < 1){
                        $vari="";
                    }else{
                        $vari = "-".$rows['variante'];
                    }

                    $product = '
        <tr>
          <td style="width:100px; "><img src="../'.$rows['image'].'" style="width:90%;border: 1px solid black;"></td>
          <td>'.$num.''.$vari.'</td>
          <td style="width:15%;">
              <select name="fabric" class="fabric select form-control selectpicker" required="" data-id="'.$id.'">
                '. $fabric_options . '  
              </select>
          </td>

          <td>
                <select  data-id="'.$id.'" class="select size form-control selectpicker" required style="width:80%;" >
                <option>Select size</option>
                <option value="'.$t50.'">50x'.$t50.'</option>
                <option value="'.$t45.'">45x'.$t45.'</option>

              </select>
          </td>
          <td class="product'.$id.'">'.$value.'</td>
          <td class="icms">R$: '.$_SESSION['icms'].'</td>
          <td class="total'.$id.'" data-id="'.$id.'">R$: '.$value * $_SESSION['icms'] .' </td>
          <td> 
             '.$btn_add.' '.$btn_remove.' '.$btn_delete.'
          </td>
        </tr>';
        echo $product;  

        } 
      } 
    }
  }   
}
```

and this is where my calculations are made..

calculates.php

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/json');

 include_once '../incluedes/conn_cms.php'; //session allways start here

 if(isset($_GET["size_id"],$_GET["fabric_id"],$_GET['prod_id'])){
    $size_id=$_GET["size_id"] ;
    $fabric_id=$_GET["fabric_id"] ;
    $prod   = $_GET['prod_id'];
    $prodname = 'product_'.$prod;

    $query3 =" SELECT * FROM valores_almofadas WHERE size='$size_id' AND price_id ='$fabric_id'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query3);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        if($_SESSION['estado'] == 'SP'){
            $ICMS = $rows['icms_7'];
        }else{
            $ICMS = $rows['icms_12'];
        }
        $_SESSION['icms']=$ICMS;

    } 
    echo json_encode( $_SESSION['icms']);
}
```

how can i make my dropdown work foreach product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `var fabricID = $(".fabric").val()` is selecting the value from the first element it finds with the `fabric` class. This will be the same element (the first one) every time, no matter how many elements exist on the page with that class.

You need to select the value from the correct elements. This is made slightly trickier by the fact that you need to send both the fabric and size values simultaneously. Luckily you have got the row ID as a data attribute on both the `<select>` elements, so we can use this to match them up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.fabric, .size').on('change', sendData);

  function sendData() {
   //use the data-id attribute of the selected element to match the correct elements
   var id = $(this).data("id");
    var fabricID = $('.fabric[data-id=' + id + ']').val(); 
    var sizeID   = $('.size[data-id=' + id + ']').val();

    if ( fabricID !== "" && sizeID !== "") {
      $.ajax({
            type     : 'GET',
            url      : 'calculates.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            data     : {
                prod_id:id,
                fabric_id: fabricID,
                size_id: sizeID
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('.icms' + id).text(data.val);

        });
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: getting an error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list something with the vars

Comment: i change to this var fabricID = $('.fabric[data-id='+id +']').val();  the syntax error now is gone,one thing is that the first cost of product is repeating to the others

Comment: I've corrected the syntax error. For the product cost being shown to all the others...you only have one single `$_SESSION["icms"] value`. You overwrite it on every call to calculates.php, no matter which product is being calculated. Surely you need one value per product ID? I suspect that is not helping.

Comment: Yes you are correct i need a $icms per product ID, icms is the cost